# Kubuntu Network Manager Question

Tags: wireless, network-manager, configuration

I run Kubuntu 20..04.1 LTS. and I have a question about the "Available Networks" that appear in my "Network Connections" System Setting Module.  Specifically, can I hide some of them?

My neighbors have like 6000 wireless networks between their houses (slight exaggeration) and for many of them I am at extreme range.  As a result, they keep popping back in and out, causing the list to constantly re-justify.  It's not uncommon that I bring up the list and go to select my wireless network (no, I don't leave this system connected to wireless all the time), and right before I select the network, the list re-justifies and I wind up clicking one of the bloody neighbor's networks, disconnecting my VPN, etc.

So I'd like to be able to permanently hide selected networks, or perhaps ANY network other than the ones I select.  I've been digging around, and can't find a way to do this.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think you missed the point completely.  Why would I want to set "auto-reconnect" to certain networks when I clearly said I purposely leave the machine disconnected from wireless most of the time?

I just want to be able to select certain "available networks" and hide them, so that I never see them again.  I will never attempt to connect to them purposely.

I'm just looking for a way to hide networks that I don't want to see or access.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Auto-connect is different from turning your wireless on/off. They are separate controls. First you turn your wireless on, then the system auto-connects. When you want to be offline, turn your wireless off. You seem to be "just" attracted to a preferred solution that does not exist.

Comment: Auto connect won't work for me.  I have multiple networks in this house, for different purposes, and none of them broadcast SSID.  That's why this system gets manually connected to wireless, only as needed, then immediately disconnected when done with that task.